# Populate array with input values

Tags: arrays, angular, input

I try to push the strings from an input into an array so after I can assign that array to a `<select>` and each `<option>` should be one string from the input. This is what I've done so far and this is the error I get and I have no idea how to do it and because I cannot find some reliable information about Angular arrays only hardcoding examples I would like to provide me an example how can I do this.

[image]

This is my HTML code in which I have just an input to add player's name

```ts
    <div class="addplayer">
      <form (submit)="onSubmit()" #formName="ngForm">
        <h2>Add a new player</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.Jimbo"
      [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" id="name" #name="ngModel" required>
      {{model.name}}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!formName.form.valid">Add Player</button>
  </form>
```

Here is my ts file with the function onSubmit() in which I try to push the names from the input into the array

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AddPlayer } from './add-player';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-player',
  templateUrl: './add-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-player.component.css']
})
export class AddPlayerComponent{

  name:string = "";
  onSubmit() {
    this.listOfNames.push(this.name)
    console.log(this.listOfNames);
  }
}
```

And here is another ts file with the constructor

```ts
export class AddPlayer {
  constructor(
    public listOfNames: string[] = []
    ){}
}
```

Comment: `AddPlayerComponent` doesn't have a `listOfNames` property, so it's unclear what you think `this.listOfNames` would do in that class.

Comment: `AddPlayer` class isn't really used anywhere in your code and is confusing to the question. You could try to add `this.name` into a local variable. Just declare the variable in before hand as @jonrsharpe mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using `name` both for `ngModel` and template reference. You need to change either. Also like mentioned, you need to declare the array `listOfNames`. Also your `model` is a string, so there is no such thing as `model.name` that you are trying to display in your template.

Modify the code to the following, here I have decided to change the name of the variable, but as mentioned, you can also change the name of the template reference variable.

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formName="ngForm">
  <h2>Add a new player</h2>
  <input [(ngModel)]="nameModel" name="name" id="name" #name="ngModel" required>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!formName.form.valid">Add Player</button>
</form>
```

and TS:

```ts
nameModel:string = "";
listOfNames = [];

onSubmit() {
  this.listOfNames.push(this.nameModel)
  console.log(this.listOfNames);
  this.nameModel = '';
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pupewv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You try to push into `this.listOfNames` which should be declared in your `AddPlayerComponent` like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AddPlayer } from './add-player';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-player',
  templateUrl: './add-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-player.component.css']
})
export class AddPlayerComponent{
  listOfNames = [];
  name:string = "";
  onSubmit() {
    this.listOfNames.push(this.name)
    console.log(this.listOfNames);
  }
}
```